# Merging uneven tables in R all=TRUE

Tags: r, merge

I am trying to merge two tables in R that look like this:

table_1:

```
id  1_query 1_hit
1   aaa aaa
1   aaa aab
2   ccc ccc
3   ddd eee
```

table 2:

```
id  2_query 2_hit
1   aaa aaa
1   aaa abb
2   ccc ccc
2   cdc cdc
```

Unfortunately the ID is not unique, for every ID i have different "queries" and "hits" in different tables, yet the ID is needed and is something I would like to merge the tables by.

The desired output should look like this:

merged:

```
id  1_query 1_hit   2_query 2_hit
1   aaa aaa aaa aaa
1   aaa aab NA  NA
1   NA  NA  aaa abb
2   ccc ccc ccc ccc
2   NA  NA  cdc cdc
3   ddd eee NA  NA
```

What I tried so far was `merge(table1, table2, all=TRUE)` 
but that outputs table like this:

```
id X1_query X1_hit X2_query X2_hit
1      aaa    aaa      aaa    aaa
1      aaa    aaa      aaa    abb
1      aaa    aab      aaa    aaa
1      aaa    aab      aaa    abb
2      ccc    ccc      ccc    ccc
2      ccc    ccc      cdc    cdc
3      ddd    eee     <NA>   <NA>
```

I am sorry if this is something trivial.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try, if `dat1` and `dat2` are the two datasets,

```
dat1$Newcol <-as.character(interaction(dat1[,2:3]))
dat2$Newcol <- as.character(interaction(dat2[,2:3]))
 merge(dat1, dat2, by=c("id", "Newcol"), all=TRUE)[,-2]
 #   id X1_query X1_hit X2_query X2_hit
 #1  1      aaa    aaa      aaa    aaa
 #2  1      aaa    aab     <NA>   <NA>
 #3  1     <NA>   <NA>      aaa    abb
 #4  2      ccc    ccc      ccc    ccc   
 #5  2     <NA>   <NA>      cdc    cdc
 #6  3      ddd    eee     <NA>   <NA>
```